# How to put and deploy angular frontend in laravel backend

Tags: angular, laravel

I have written a singe page app with angular for the frontend and laravel for the backend. I want to deploy it on a host, but I can't figure it out.

What I've done so far:

1. I ran `ng build --prod`
2. I put the dist folder in laravel's public folder
3. I changed `.htaccess` file: `RewriteRule ^ dist/index.html [L]`

When I run `php artisan serve`, the app starts on `localhost:8000`, but when I go on `localhost:8000`, it shows me the standard laravel starting page.

I don't know if my approach is good, but it seems like a logical one.

Comment: Put your angular over different subdomain, like app.yourdomain.com. don't mix backend and frontend deployment.

Comment: But I want to put the built angular app in laravel public folder, to be the view of the laravel

Comment: It won't work. Or you use different subdomains or subfolders. Under same folders the Laravel router will assume and avoid angular router to work or vice-versa

Answer (score -1):

Your question is confused for me. If you write or run the `php artisan serve` command, it will place your laravel application by default inside port 8000 and obviously open the welcome.blade.php page. You have to open your angular application and call your API in laravel from another location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559445/how-can-angular-4-use-with-laravel-5-5-together

The second answer is what I've done so far. Can laravel open the built angular app, and not welcome.blade.php.page. In short: I want the laravel view to be the angular app